# What happens if I define $C^0(I;X)$ like this (without caring about continuity)?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

For $X$ a Banach space, let me define the space $C^0([0,T];X)$ to consist of elements $u:[0,T] \to X$ such that
$$\lVert u \rVert_{C^0} := \max_{t \in [0,T]}\lVert u(t) \rVert_X < \infty.$$
So the difference is that I don't care about continuity of $u$ in $t$. This defines a norm.

For completeness, let $u_n \in C^0$ be a Cauchy sequence. Then $\{u_n(t)\}_n$ is convergent for each $t \in [0,T]$. Let's say $u_n(t) \to u(t) \in X$ for each $t$. Then $u$ has finite $C^0$ norm right?

So what is the use of this space? Is there something good about it?

Comment: You should replace $\max$ by $\sup$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Does it matter? because the interval is compact.

Comment: Yes. Discontinuous functions on an interval needn't take on their supremum. Just consider changing the identity function on $[0,T]$ to take on the value $0$ at $T$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\kappa$ be the cardinality of $[0,T]$, then your definition of $C^0([0,T],X)$ is nothing more that $\infty$-sum of $\kappa$ copies of the space $X$, i.e.
$$
C^0([0,T],X)=\ell_\infty(\kappa,X)
$$

Comment: I looked up cardinality, is $\kappa = T$?

Comment: No, $\kappa$ is amount of points in the interval $[0,T]$. In fact $\kappa=\mathfrak{c}$, i. e. the cardinality of continuum.

Answer (score 1):

This is the set of bounded functions of $[0,T]$ to $X$ (mostly we assume $X = R$, but one can define this of course more generally). This is a very general assumption and therefore contains very 'wild' functions like non-measurable functions (assuming these exist). However, due to the very strong norm, it is still a usefull function space, since convergence is very strong and therefore these exotic functions do not occur at the end of sequences of non-exotic functions.

If you have any Banach Spaces $X$ and $Y$, then you can define $C^{0}(X,Y)$ consisting of all functions $u$ from $X$ to $Y$ such that
$$
 \| u \|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in X} \| u(x) \|_{Y} < \infty.
$$
The norm $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ is also called the supremum-norm.

Comment: Thanks, so you say a non-measurable function can't be the limit in this norm of measurable functions.

Comment: Yes I do, but it still would be if we had not such a strong convergence (for example pointwise convergence, or even pointwise convergence almost everywhere).